# compare first word from 2 columns

Tags: excel, compare

I am trying to get a true/false from a comparison of the first word in 2 columns with the answer in a third column. I have done it with characters but I want to refine it.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you told us how you did it with characters.

Comment: =IF(MID(E2,1,6)=MID(I2,1,6),TRUE,FALSE) But this sometimes failed when the word (in this case a name was longer than the 6 letters but different after that ie Washington or Washingborough. It would also be false for Names that were shorter than 6 letters !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I solved this with the following gigantic formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)=LEFT(B1,FIND(" ",B1)-1),TRUE,FALSE),IFERROR(IF(A1=LEFT(B1,FIND(" ",B1)-1),TRUE,FALSE),IFERROR(IF((LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)=B1),TRUE,FALSE),IF(A1=B1,TRUE,FALSE))))
```

I broke your problem down into 4 different cases:

1. both columns have multiple words
2. first column has 1 word, second has multiple words
3. first column has multiple words, second has 1 word
4. both columns have 1 word

Here are the values I tested:

```
| Main St.  | Main Street | TRUE  |
| First St. | Main Street | FALSE |
| Main      | Main St.    | TRUE  |
| Main      | First St.   | FALSE |
| Main St.  | Main        | TRUE  |
| Main St.  | First       | FALSE |
| Main      | Main        | TRUE  |
| Main      | First       | FALSE |
```

The IFERROR function handles the errors for columns with single words, so if both columns don't have multiple words then we check if the 2nd column has multiple words, then we test the first column for multiple words, then we assume both columns only have one word.

Comment: That works brilliantly !! Just what I wanted, it identifies all of the places I need to look into. Some are just inconsistent naming ie hyphenated with or without spaces and some are 's' on the end or not. Thanks for the effort you went to !!!